# Make the whole app as subscription

Tags: android, google-play, subscription, android-billing

I have read about [subscription](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) but all of them is about in app items. Are there apis or methods to make the full app as a subscription? I have also tried in Google console making a new app but there is only FREE and PAID option. I want my app to be subscription like the magazines in Google play. Can anyone provide a reference or is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

Your subscription would be an IN APP item. You would check if their subscription is active in the app and if not disallow use of the app.

For instance check the subscription in the main activity and if they dont have an active subscription then either send them to the subscription activity or whatever, and if they decide not to subscribe simply exit.

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is create a bare bones app that show users what they can accomplish with your app, like if this was an accounting app, they can add only 3 items,etc.

Then have an in-app subscription item that is "unlimited items" ,etc. They buy that.

I'm doing subscriptions for specific features in my app, like multiple accounts is a sub item and I'm planning on adding more, like "admin" etc.